# Azure Data Factory - MQ data flow

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, mq, azure-data-factory

I have been tasked to create an Azure Data Factory pipeline that will process messages being generated from an MQ Farm and that are stored in Data Storage in .xml format and then ingest them in a SharePoint Table.

The question is how would your approach be in that scenario to slice the .xml files in smaller pieces? The .xml files are nesting a lot of records in one file (with a valid separator on each record) and I wish to discard some while process the valid ones.

P.S.: For receiving and storing the MQ Farm messages I am using a logic app before Azure Data Factory

Comment: You are using Logic Apps, MQ, XML files, Sharepoint and now you want to bring ADF into the mix. The technology complexity alarm is going off.

Comment: Well point A is MQ on prem and point B Sharepoint Online. Any suggestions are welcomed

Comment: I assume this is an IBM MQ? What is the sharepoint list being used for? I guess the MQ is sending messages that are XML and that can't be changed. That's quite an impedance mismatch there. Digging around, there doesn't seem to be a simple way to implement this. ADF can't read directly from MQ, and is not very good at shredding XML. It sounds like you have some nasty XML parsing requirements there.

Comment: I think you could go two ways on this. You could probably use event hubs to capture the XML and dump it to blob storage, then use Azure functions to batch apply that to a sharepoint list. Or you might be able to use Azure functions to read straight out of event hubs. It's probably just going to be easier to write some custom C# inside an Azure function to do the hard work rather of shredding the XML and loading it to the SP list, rather than trying to get ADF to do it.

Comment: ADF is great but quickly runs out of steam when you need to do complex stuff like shred XML

Comment: Hey Nick! Exactly its how you described the architecture. The Sharepoint is actually hosting a frontend custom application with its data whereas the backend is running on Azure. Incredible mix if you ask me so I am trying to somehow integrate my part in this big picture. The MQ is linking many more systems so yes I cant change the format of the xml data arriving to me. I will try the Event Hubs and the Azure Functions but C# aint that much my cup of tea yet! Thanks for the suggestion anyways. I was hoping ADF could fit the excercise but its like trying to fit an S sized shirt to Mike Tyson.

Comment: Yes there’s a real impedance mismatch there. I can tell you that my colleague tried to shred XML in ADF but it just got too hard and he had to use Azure functions. It depends how complicated the XML is

Comment: I’ll just add that I highly recommend using PowerApps for front end work if you are already committed to Azure.

Comment: It has a specific structure with nice and defined tags and separators but those xml files can be really long and we are talking of volumes of 10k xml files a day with 40-50 messages in one .xml to be parsed.

Comment: And you are loading all that data into a share point list?

Comment: Yup, the customer is actually populating the Sharepoint application through this Sharepoint list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the solution was more obvious than previously thought... Solved from the logic app designer and saving to blob

[image]

Comment: This neither shreds XML nor saves to a share point list but I’m glad you got a result.